# How to pass two actions in Caliburn Micro gesture key bindings?

Tags: c#, xaml, caliburn.micro

I want to do something like this in Caliburn Micro is possibile, and if is possible how can I do it?

The method:

```
public void DoStuff(System.Action action1, System.Action action2)
{
    action1.Invoke();
    action2.Invoke();
}
```

XAML attach line:

```
[Gesture Control+Delete] = [DoStuff(action1, action2)];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could invoke two actions as follows.

```
"[Gesture Control+Delete]=[Method1];[Gesture  Control+Delete]=[Method2]"
```

Comment: Thank you! It is a solution but not the best one, because if I many buttons, I had to add many gestures to the same control. Or if I have a button that must call 5 methods, I had to add 5 gestures to that button. I'm still waiting for another solution.

Comment: @EduardStefanescu Would be interesting to find a solution as you desired. Btw, how are you passing one System.Action parameter ?